# How to change directory using script

Tags: bash

I have this script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/somedir
pwd
```

it works as expected, but I would like this script to transport me to /home/user/somedir, but I stay in the same dir.

How to write script that will transport me (in gnome-terminal) to /home/user/somedir?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't "cd" work in a shell script?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481715/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 16):

You need to `source` your script. If not it will be run in a separate subshell, changing the working directory of the subshell but not of the shell you run it in.

To source it :

```
. myfile.sh
```

or

```
source myfile.sh
```

*You can read more [here](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html)*

Comment: I was just going to add that.... UAdadapter if you were running the shelll script like sh myfile.sh or ./myfile.sh it would run as danjil described. Either of danjil's options should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

## Use `exec bash` at the end

> A bash script operates on its current environment or on that of its
>   children, but never on its parent environment.

However, this question often gets asked because one wants to be left at a bash prompt in a certain directory after the execution of a bash script from another directory.

If this is the case, simply execute a child bash instance at the end of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/somedir
exec bash
```